# Number of integer solutions: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = N$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Help me please with some ideas to find number of integer solutions.

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = N$

Time limit - $1$ second, $N \leq 10^9$.

My wrong algorithm:

1) Calculate prime numbers on $(0,\sqrt{N})$

2) Compute $\sqrt{N}$ numbers $A_i = N-z^2, z = \sqrt{N}$.

3) For all $A_i$ check that it not include primes $4k+3$ in odd powers.

4)Find answer for each $A_i$ with brute force.

Running time of algorithm  $\approx 1.7$ seconds but it is bad.

Comment: Do you know any character theory? If you do there is a simple method in Ireland and Rosen's [excellent book](http://www.amazon.ca/Classical-Introduction-Modern-Number-Theory/dp/038797329X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1338908510&sr=8-1).

Comment: Thank, but I don't know character theory. Is it really need for solving this problem ?

Comment: I'm sure there are probably other methods. This is the one I know though. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will to try read this book)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a paper [Some Formulae...](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.28.19) that gives an explicit formula that may be easier to compute.

It also has one for the number of partitions into 2 squares, which you could use in your step 4) if that's easier.

You can consult [A000164](http://oeis.org/A000164) and [A000161](http://oeis.org/A000161) at OEIS for more references.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want too involved math and just look at it as an algorithm question, the way to do this would probably be like this:

```
int upper_bound = ceil (sqrt(N/3));
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < upper_bound; i++) {
  int i2 = i * i;
  int j = i;
  int k = floor (sqrt(N-i2));

  while (j <= k) {
    int j2 = j * j;
    int k2 = k * k;
    int sum = i2 + j2 + k2;

    if (sum < N) {
      j ++;
    } else if (sum > N) {
      k --;
    } else {
      count ++;
      j ++;
    }
  }
}

return count;
```

Number of loop iterations is roughly upper_bound$^2$/2 which is about N/6. Should do it.

Comment: Thank, but for $N = 10^9$ O(N) is very slow.